# How to get total amount of rows while using limit when using PDO prepared statements?

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, limit

I found some similar ones, but not the exact one that I need:

- [Do the work but not using PDO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1126026/4984911)
- [Using PDO but not using LIMIT](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17897289/using-pdo-do-i-really-need-to-run-two-separate-prepared-statements-to-get-the-n)

Background information:
 I am using MySQL with PDO class

Currently, I am using two queries as follows:

**To get one page of data**:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM `tab`
WHERE `condition` = :condition 
LIMIT $page_size OFFSET $offset";

$array = array('condition'=>$condition);
$mysql = $pdo->prepare($sql);
$mysql->execute($array);
```

**To get total amount of rows:**

```
$sql = "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `tab`
WHERE `condition` = :condition";

$array = array('condition'=>$condition);
$mysql = $pdo->prepare($sql);
$mysql->execute($array);
```

Comment: Can you show your code / attempt to achieve it ?

Comment: @SulthanAllaudeen, see the new question content.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS` command to tell MySQL to return the total of the matching records

```
$sql = "SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS * FROM `tab`
WHERE `condition` = :condition 
LIMIT $page_size OFFSET $offset";
```

To get the total rows found you can run this query

```
SELECT FOUND_ROWS()
```

However, it is often faster to execute 2 separate queries than using `SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS`. Here is a [benchmark to explain](https://www.percona.com/blog/2007/08/28/to-sql_calc_found_rows-or-not-to-sql_calc_found_rows/)

[you can read more about this here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/186588/which-is-fastest-select-sql-calc-found-rows-from-table-or-select-count)